# change the target on a shortcut in VB.Net (((E invalid arg)))

Tags: vb.net

how do i change the target on a shortcut?

```
Private Function CreateShortCut(ByVal TargetName As String, ByVal ShortCutPath As String, ByVal ShortCutName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim oLink As Object
    'you don’t need to import anything in the project reference to create the Shell Object

    Try

        oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        oLink = oShell.CreateShortcut(ShortCutPath & "\" & ShortCutName & ".lnk")
        oLink.TargetPath = TargetName
        oLink.WindowStyle = 1
        oLink.Save()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Function
```

My OpenFile Path:

```
Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`

    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName

End if
```

want my shortcut to become:

```
"MyPath\executable.exe" --start-time=120
```

using this, my shortcut just becomes

```
"MyPath\executable.exe"
```

if I try to change something, I get the error

> The parameter is incorrect (exception from hResult) 0x80070057 ((E invalid arg)))

Code: more detailed for openfile dialog.

```
    Dim TargetName As String = "C:\"
    Dim ShortCutPath As String = "C:\"
    Dim ShortCutName As String = "Executable"
    Dim ApplicationPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\preset")

    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Executable|*.exe;*"

    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        ' TargetName = """" & OpenFileDialog1.FileName & str
        'Dim str As String = """ --start-time=60"
        TargetName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName 'working

        ' MyShortcut = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(MyPath)

    End If

    CreateShortCut(TargetName, ApplicationPath, ShortCutName)
```

Comment: Why are you using WScript inside of VB.Net?

Comment: If you do want to go the WScript route, you'll need to add arguments to your shortcut.  See example #2 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh

Comment: yes, work with argument, thank.